# Field Overwrite does not work within a method body - Java

Tags: java, variable-assignment, overwrite

Here's a question that goes right back to basics (I think) although had me stumped in a recent coding project I undertook with a few friends.

Here's code variation one:

```
public class Test {

private String test;

public Test(){
    test = "tester";
    changeString(test);
}

public void changeString(String t){
    t = "blue apples";
}

public String getTest(){
    return test;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Test t = new Test();
    System.out.println(t.getTest());
}
}
```

Why does the program print out "tester" instead of "blue apples"? Shouldn't the method changeString(String) turn the field 'test' into "blue apples"?

Thanks for your responses in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is pass by value and not pass by reference. Therefore, the changes made to the passed `t` String, won't be reflected in your `test` String.

```
public void changeString(String t){
    t = "blue apples";
    test = t; // Include this line to assign the value of `t` to `test`.
}
```

Comment: @user2853506 - Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing,

```
 test = "tester";
 changeString(test);
```

String is immutable in java.

```
public void changeString(String t){
    t = "blue apples";
}
```

In the above lines you are changing the value of the parameter passed to that method, Not the `test`.

To see change try

```
public void changeString(String t){
    t= "blue apples";
    test=t;  // now assigned the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you assign `"Tester"` to `test`.  Next you call `changeString` passing it a reference of `test`.

This method simply assigns `"blue apples"` to `t`.  In doing so, it creates a new `String` before making the assignment.  Because `t` is passed by value, the change is not reflected when the method returns

Instead, you would need to do something more like...

```
public void changeString(String t){
    text = t;
}
```

And use `changeString("blue apples");`

or

```
public String changeString(){
    return "blue apples";
}
```

And use `test = changeString();`

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable in JAVA. Immutablity means once an instance is created it remains the same. In your case

1. In your case you created a tester reference to point to a new String "Tester"
2. Since string is immutable when you passed the object to the method and tried to reassign the reference to a new String "Blue Apples" what you did was created a reference t in the scope of method which pointed to blue apples. If you would had had printed t you would have got "Blue Apples" since the scope of t is till the method.
3. After returning the tester reference still points to the same old string "tester" and hence it gets printed.

As with String all other wrapper classes are also immutable. You would observe same behavior with Integer, Boolean objects

Answer (score -1):

This happens because String object is immutable, hence cannot change its value post assignment. You can use StringBuffer or StringBuilder isntead